# Angular Docker-Container is not showing although technically running

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem that may be an easy one for someone that is more familiar with docker and angular than I am.

I already set up a nodejs-backend for my app and the container is working perfectly fine.

But I got issues with my frontend container. It keeps saying

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URWYU.png)

but if I go into chrome and go on localhost4200 it shows the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page.

So I have no clue or any kind of a reference point on how I could solve this problem.

To give context, I post my Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and my package.json below.

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA3hu.png)

[docker compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE37w.png)

[package json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VenuQ.png)

I hope anyone had this problem before me, so I can start deploying my app. Thank you!

I already gathered through almost all possible tutorials online but found nothing too helpful.
I hope anyone had this problem before me, so I can start deploying my app. Thank you!

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)